# Python - Mailosaur get HTML Element

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So I'm using Mailosaur and I want to get the text of an HTML element in the E-Mail, in the Docs it says something like that:

```py
# Wait for the message
message = client.messages.get("{SERVER_ID}", criteria)

# Extract the verification code from HTML
dom = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
verification_code = dom.find('.verify-code').text

print(verification_code)
```

But I get the error:

```py
    dom = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
NameError: name 'html' is not defined
```

I tried something like that too:

```py
dom = BeautifulSoup(message.html, 'html.parser')
```

But I get the error:

```py
TypeError: object of type 'MessageContent' has no len()
```

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks.

Edit:
So here is the rest of the Code:

```py
from mailosaur.models import SearchCriteria
from mailosaur import MailosaurClient
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

client = MailosaurClient('MyAPIKey')

criteria = SearchCriteria()
criteria.sent_to = "something.{ServerID}@mailosaur.io"

message = client.messages.get(ServerID, criteria)

if 'Email Verification' in message.subject: # Works
    dom = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') # Doesn't work
    verification_code = dom.find('') # Not Sure how to use this here, but that shouldn't be a big problem
    print(verification_code)
```

Edit 2:
So I got it working but I'm not sure on how to use dom.find('').
The HTML Element looks like this:
`<div style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; color:#313131; text-align: center; font-size: 50px; letter-spacing: 20px; line-height: 120px;"> 619718` the Code at the end is the think I need

Comment: What's in the `message` var? It should be it instead of `html`, AFAIK.

Comment: I will edit the Question and add more context @Tico

Comment: The first argument is the HTML code that BS uses to create the `BeautifulSoup` object. [Here's the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start). `html` is not defined, hence the error.

Comment: I haven't user Mailosaur before, but by looking through their [docs](https://docs.mailosaur.com/docs/testing-email-in-python#extracting-content-from-email-html) it seems that if you want the html of the email message you need the `message.html.body` field.

Comment: Thanks @DanBrezeanu but now I have another problem, how should I use dom.find('') (The HTML Element looks like this:

<div style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; color:#313131; text-align: center; font-size: 50px; letter-spacing: 20px; line-height: 120px;">
619718

And the code at the end is the element I want)

Comment: Considering this is your only `<div>` tag, then the code would be extracted by `code = dom.find('div').getText()` . If that is not your only `<div>` tag then you should use `findAll('div')` which returns a list of the `div` elements then determime the appropiate index so to extract the only `div` you're interested in.